# Azure Function - disable all the Functions in an app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

One can use app settings `AzureWebJobs.<FUNCTION_NAME>.Disabled` [to disable individual Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function) in an Azure Function. However, that of course requires that you know all the Function names.

Is there a way to disable all Functions in a similar way? (and no, just Stopping the function app is not an option).

Comment: I suppose that using some management api one could write a script to do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060814/disable-azure-function-via-azurecli-does-not-disable-function. Just add a call that lists all functions.

Comment: thanks @PeterBons but I would need to add a setting before I even deploy any function into the Function app. Otherwise they will start up before I have a chance to disable them...

Comment: So you want them all to be disabled on each deployment? When are they enabled?

Comment: yes, they are a semi-hot-standby deployment. They will be enabled when failover is required. So far I built this with a custom attribute, but now I need to add this to every function (`[Disable("FUNCTION_DISABLED")]`)

Answer (score 0):

In Local Azure Function Project, we can add the disabled attribute for the multiple functions we need to disable:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobs.BlobTriggerFunction.Disabled": true,
    "AzureWebJobs.SingleTonTimerFunction.Disabled": true
  }
}
```

As you're adding the custom attribute using C# class library in every function code like `[Disable("FUNCTION_DISABLED")]` which is also considerable but using application settings is recommended as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal#other-methods).

[image]

I have 3 different functions in which 2 are disabled using the above code.

One of the similar issues is in open state in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2412) regarding disabling all the functions at a time is a feature request and there are some temporary workarounds given which is possible using App Settings in the Portal Azure Function Configuration Menu but that is regarding to specific slot.